# mock.patch in pytest fixture doesn't work when other tests have run

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, fixtures

Given the following code and tests:

```py
# some module

from other.module import a_func  # returns False by default


def do_stuff():
    return "banana" if a_func() else "pear"

#############################

# tests in a different module

@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture():
    with mock.patch("other.module.a_func", lambda: True):
        yield


class TestMyStuff:
    def test_something(self):
        assert do_stuff() == "pear"

    def test_something_else(self, my_fixture):
        assert do_stuff() == "banana"
```

The last test fails if I run all my tests at once, but succeeds if I only run it.

I know that this might be due to the fact that by the time `test_something_else` runs, `other.module.a_func` has already been imported and loaded, and so the patch isn't taking effect.

How do I make it work, or how should I restructure my code so that I can mock the result of `a_func` to test different outcomes of `do_stuff`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should do

```
mock.patch("some.module.a_func")
```

instead of

```
mock.patch("other.module.a_func")
```

`from other.module import a_func` means that `a_func` becomes part of the `some.module`, so patching the origin of function definition has no effect - instead, patching should be done where the function is used. Read [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) for more info.

Comment: I must have read that and pytest's explation a thousand times, not to mention all questions similar to mine, but somehow your short example finally made it click. Thanks. :)

Comment: I'm trying to create a fixture in conftest that will be available to multiple modules. Is there a way to patch all modules without manually writing out each one?